# jquery load() doesnot work with isotope plugin

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a problem with AJAX `load()` function. I am using the isotope plugin to animate my div section.

I need to load the content of Div by AJAX`load()`. When I apply `.load()` on the same div where I applied the isotope plugin, it does not work. On the other hand when I apply the same `.load()` function with some other div it works fine.

I have searched a lot to solve the problem but have not had any success. Can you help me please?

Here are the links: http://demo.webhole.net/load-a-page-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do you need to rebind plugin to div after loading? When you load the content into div you destroy old content of this div with old binded event callbacks.

Comment: i think i want to bind the isotope function after all the div section execute successfully ?? would u help me how am gonna do that.??